# What image editor do you recommend to create cool UI elements?

Tags: user-interface, image-manipulation, image-editor

I sincerly believe that cool-looking UI has significant contribution to the value of your software. It not only significantly improves sales but also ease user-buyin, upgrading willingness, or just causes some pleasant moments to the user.

To get cool UI, you will need a lot of images, and you need to play frequently with transparancy.

[image]

**Question 1:** What image editor do you use/recommend to produce 3D looking images, metalic reflections, glowing text, shadows, or making a button image "disabled-looking"? (freewares are preferred)

**Question 2:** Could you point to "how-to"-s and guiding documents on how to achieve these visual effects?

Comment: I keep clicking but the play button doesn't do anything...

Comment: :D Don't give up easily!

Comment: Be carefull when making non standard UI elements -- if it looks cool and even makes funny sounds, but doesn't support left to right layout, keyboard navigation, accessibility or any other small things already built into standard controls -- you are ending up in worse shape than if you just used plain Win2000 look. 
Even though some clueless users might not think so due to ferret-shock.

Answer (score 3):

The best image editor to achieve these effects is probably Adobe Fireworks, which definitely doesn't come under the freeware category at around £700 )and probably around $700 as well, although I haven't checked).

The best freeware editor in my opinion would be [Paint.net](http://getpaint.net).

However, I also think that you should seriously consider using the default UI components where available, as using non-standard widgets can significantly reduce the usability of your product.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org) - it now has much more flexible control over gradients and opacity, which are key to creating good GUI elements.

Answer (score 2):

We use Adobe illustator and Photoshop to create all of our Icons and Images, and when you know how to use it, you can make pretty good UI elements.
Paint.net is as a freeware good for bitmaps and icons (a mini photoshop).
but for icons i would recomend [axialis icon workshop](http://www.axialis.com/iconworkshop/)

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a budget, I like free so Inkscape is my vote too. There are plenty of tutorials on the web to help and once you learn a couple of usability points with it, it's a pretty easy application to use. Being vector based has benefits too as you can change images other people make pretty easily.

http://howto.nicubunu.ro/shiny_web_buttons_inkscape/

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what platform you're using, you can use Expression Blend to edit your GUI controls in WPF (.NET 3.5 SP1) to look however you want.

Otherwise there's always Photoshop.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I use Paintshop, mostly. I have a copy of Inkscape for whatever needs to scale well.

Answer (score 0):

Why has no one mentioned **GIMP**? It's free and very powerful. I can remember a webpage with amazing scripts to GIMP for every effect you asked for it. I am searching for it right now and will update the question with a link once I find it.